Way to measure volume of hole scanned by 3D laser device and CAD
I'm not a mechanical engineer so please let me know if my question is not clear.
There is a hole generated on a pipe wall as shown in the upper figure. I would like to measure the volume of the hole to investigate the small difference of the shape and size between the planned hole and the hole actually made. The hole is scanned by a 3D external laser and make a scanned image which is the solid line in the lower figure. The scanned image is converted to CAD such as STP & STL files. I believe we can measure the hole volume which is the red shaded area in the lower figure, using the CAD software like solidworks or Autodesk Fusion, but I'm not sure the detail procedure. Would you please let me know what software is useful and how can I use the software? Even if you share some texts or youtube videos, I would appreciate it.
I also have to mention that there is one significant problem. Since the laser is irradiated from outside the pipe, the hole wall close to the pipe inside is not scanned much as shown in the dash line in the lower figure. I need to complement the missing data. We know the inside and outside diameter of the pipe, so I believe we can complete it. But I'm completely new to 3D laser measurement and CAD, I'm very happy if you could tell me in detail.


why do you need to measure the volume, why not calculate the volume?

We would like to know the small difference of the shape and size between the planned hole and the hole actually made on the pipe.

please add that explanation to your question

close the object then calculate the volume in a polygon editor.

@jsotola I edited the question.

@joojaa Thank you for the comment. I found the youtube videos that I can measure the volume if I close the inlet and outlet. If you know how we can extrapolate the missing part, please let me know.

So most software for dealing with scanned data can close volumes, so for example you could use meshlab for the job. If not then you need to estimate the hole size slince it into a circle then extrude that.

anyway we can not really help you beyond this with what you have given
